# CSS box-shadow hidden

Tags: html, css, hover, shadow

I have a `box-shadow` on my `.nav-item:hover`. Unfortunately, the shadow is being covered/hidden by the other elements.
I tried to set a `z-index` and `positon:relative` on `.nav-item`, but that does not fix my problem.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
http://higps.org:8000/pitoNew/

Comment: You have to set the z-index property to the divs, not to the a elements. Just add some class and :hover pseudoclass to div element that will set higher z-index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you mixed too much `z-index` on your elements. You need to apply `z-index` on your `.brick` classes.

```
#header [class*="brick"] {
   position: relative;
}

#header [class*="brick"]:hover {
   z-index: 100;
}

#header .nav-item {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 19.2px;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#header a.nav-item:hover,
#header a.nav-item:focus {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   color: #fff;
}
```

And remove all `z-index` properties from the elements inside your `.brick` div.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `box-shadow` from mouse hovering of `a` tag and add `box shadow` to mouse hovering of wrapper `div`

Try following css code

```
    #header [class*="brick"]{
      position: relative;   
    }

    #header .brick1:hover{
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
      z-index: 1010;
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to add `z-index: 999;` to the element itself and than add a bigger value on hover. That's just a `z-index` mess.

Comment: I have just manage his code, cause there already have many `z-index` applied by different classes

Comment: Yes, but that makes his code way more difficult to maintain and is simply not a good solution. Removing all the `z-index` properties from the child nodes prevents from a z-index war he is going to get in.

Comment: Yes that's true, In his code there already have a class added `.bounceIn` which has `z-index: 999`, so there need to add `z-index` more than that value